# Please Help: Need Faster Solution that Loops Through Two DataTables Quickly and Efficiently?

Tags: datatable

I have two data tables dt1 and dt2 that I need to loop through and compare two columns of dt1 to the same two columns of dt2. I'm a beginner with Linq but not sure using Linq will be faster?

Each DataTable has 4500+ rows and 514 columns of data so it's a large datatset we are dealing with here.

Column position "0" has the unique ID of each row in both datatables. I am trying to compare data in the column position "6" and also compare the data value in the column position "7" from one datatable to the other.

My code here takes about 10-15 minutes to process.

What is the best and faster solution to compare two columns from one DataTable to another?

Here is my code

```
 public void CompareDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
 {

     foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                if(row1[0].ToString() == row2[0].ToString())
                {

                    if (row1[6].ToString() != row2[6].ToString())
                    {
                        tbCPDEResults.Text += "Project ID: " + row1[0] + " has a change in INV Approval Status. \nOld Value: " + row1[6] + " \nNew Value: " + row2[6] + "\n";
                    }


                    if (row1[7].ToString() != row2[7].ToString())
                    {
                        tbCPDEResults.Text += "Project ID: " + row1[0] + " has a change in INV Progress. \nOld Value: " + row1[7] + " \nNew Value: " + row2[7] + "\n";
                    }

                }

             }//inner foreach
          }//outter foreach
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a RDMS, this is referred to as a "nested loop join," and it's generally the least efficient (though you may not have a choice).

Fortunately it sounds like you do - you can do a "merge join" instead.  Basically, you sort both tables by their shared unique identifier, then you scan through both tables in a single pass.

```
    int  rowIndex1 = 0;
    int  rowIndex2 = 0;
    while (rowIndex1 < table1.Rows.Count && rowIndex2 < table2.Rows.Count)
        {
        DataRow  row1 = table1.Rows[rowIndex1];
        DataRow  row2 = table2.Rows[rowIndex2];

        int  pk1 = Int32.Parse((string)row1[0]);
        int  pk2 = Int32.Parse((string)row2[0]);

        if (pk1 == pk2)
            {
            string  field1A = (string)row1[6];
            string  field2A = (string)row2[6];
            if (field1A != field2A)  Console.WriteLine("Field A differs for record #{0}: table 1 is {1}, tables 2 is {2}.", pk1, field1A, field2A);

            string  field1B = (string)row1[7];
            string  field2B = (string)row2[7];
            if (field1B != field2B)  Console.WriteLine("Field B differs for record #{0}: table 1 is {1}, tables 2 is {2}.", pk1, field1B, field2B);

            ++rowIndex1;
            ++rowIndex2;
            }
        else if (pk1 > pk2)
            {
            // There is no record in table 2 with this ID
            ++rowIndex2;
            }
        else if (pk2 > pk1)
            {
            // There is no record in table 1 with this ID
            ++rowIndex1;
            }
        }
```

Incidentally, this would be far easier if you could import the data into some kind of SQL server.  A single simple `SELECT` would do it.

Comment: Thanks fellas for the quick responses, I tested and ended up using the while loop solution suggested by @Jon of All Trades It works like a charm! It is much more efficient and faster than the foreach solution I had! :) I definitely would be doing this in the DB if the two datasources were static and always the same schema. Unfortunately I have to analyze the data set before sqlbulkcopy'ing into the db because of new or removed columns. Not exactly the best scenario but it is what the client wanted and is aware of the risks.

Comment: pk1 and pk2 could be strings so they are not sequential int (1,2,3,4...etc). They are mixed int and string/varchar. Sometimes a row would be in table 1 but not in table 2 and vice versa. I have other code to check for new or deleted rows but how would i modify the above answer to handle deleted or inserted rows where the pk is a string?

Comment: Mixed integers and strings?  Ick.  Well, the code above will work as well for strings, just change the type for the pk fields and drop the parsing.  Just make sure the tables are sorted with the same collation as the comparison operator you're using.  If you'd like to log records which are present in one table but not the other, you can add it where shown by the comments.

Comment: yeah the data sources are pretty challenging to manage - they can have new, renamed or deleted columns and new or deleted rows. So if my pk's are strings instead of int's, then the comparisons wouldn't still work right? if(pk1 > pk2)

Comment: The comparison is fine for strings.  Just as long as the collation the same.  For example, if your database is case-sensitive, you'll want to use a case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: ok thanks Jon. pk1 and pk2 will be something like these values: NPW103483 226723 NPW102915 NPW103047 227291 226890 227419

Answer (score 0):

Personally I hate data tables, and this is a problem best done by running separate queries on DB-level, anyway if you insist on data table solution in app itself, this is much more optimalized:

```
  public static void CompareDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2) {
    var builder = new StringBuilder(10000);

    var rows = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>(dt1.Rows.Count * 3);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows) {
      string key = row[0].ToString();
      List<DataRow> rowSet;
      if (!rows.TryGetValue(key, out rowSet)) {
        rowSet = new List<DataRow> { row };
        rows.Add(key, rowSet);
      } else {
        rowSet.Add(row);
      }
    }

    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows) {
      List<DataRow> rowSet;
      if (rows.TryGetValue(row2[0].ToString(), out rowSet)) {
        foreach (var row1 in rowSet) {
          if (row1[6].ToString() != row2[6].ToString()) {
            builder.AppendFormat("Project ID: {0} has a change in INV Approval Status. \nOld Value: {1} \nNew Value: {2}\n", row1[0], row1[6], row2[6]);
          }
          if (row1[7].ToString() != row2[7].ToString()) {
            builder.AppendFormat("Project ID: {0} has a change in INV Progress. \nOld Value: {1} \nNew Value: {2}\n", row1[0], row1[7], row2[7]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    tbCPDEResults.Text = builder.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Nice, you're giving an example of a "hash join", so between the three of us we've outlined the most common methods to join tables.  Now we just need someone to demonstrate a bitmap join.